# I get a corrupted PDF when I use Apps Script to convert a sheet to pdf and send in email

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the following code to convert the current sheet in my spreadsheet to a pdf and send it via email:

```
function sendEmailPDF(pdfName, email, title, body) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); 
  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&format=pdf'     //export as pdf
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&printtitle=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&pagenumbers=false'  //hide page numbers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false'       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      + '&gid='  //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext + sheetId, params)
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + ".pdf");

  var mailOptions = {attachments:blob, htmlBody:body};

  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0){
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email,
      title,
      "html content only",
      mailOptions
      );
    }
  }
```

Now the code executes without errors, and I receive an email with the pdf attached, but I can't open it because I get an error saying that it's corrupted and can't be opened.

When I remove the following code at line 24:
'muteHttpExceptions' : true
The code fails to execute, and I get the following error in my log:

```
Request failed for https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/146PS13Dz2HOzljUsH-umTU1FUIlcL1UCFqANAqNRUP0/exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=letter&portrait=true&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false&gid=133193667 returned code 404. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) at sendEmailPDF(sendEmailPDF:27) at submitNewProject(submitNewProject:264) at userOnEdit(On Edit:68) at userOnEdit(Code:2)
```

I have searched high and low and looked at different code samples of how to use Apps Script to send a pdf via email, but none of them seem to be working for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've copied this function and implemented the fix below and continue to get the corrupt PDF attached. Does this still work for you? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are 2 modification points in your script.

### 1. Query parameter

Please try to insert `?` as follows.

#### From :

```
var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
```

#### To :

```
var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'') + "export?";
```

### 2. Advanced parameters of MailApp.sendMail()

> attachments   BlobSource[]    an array of files to send with the email (see example)

The blob is an array. So please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
var mailOptions = {attachments:blob, htmlBody:body};
```

#### To :

```
var mailOptions = {attachments: [blob], htmlBody:body};
```

I think that when the blob is only one, `attachments:blob` works. If you want to send several blobs, please use an array.

#### Reference :

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

If this still didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: That worked!  The issue was <var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'') + "export?";>

Comment: Also, my blob was not an array, so that change didn't matter.  It worked by just implementing the first change.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Alex Libengood Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to KingOfTheNerds...
I've had a similar issue that one day my code stopped working. The solution above didn't solve my problem.
But I've found out, that the problem was in the line code:

```
var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
```

because my spreadsheet link was not ended with the word "edit".

My solution is to change mentioned line to:

```
var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit.+/,'');
```

I hope it will help somebody :)